# Numpy frombuffer error "buffer must be a multiple of element size"

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function handleNotification which is getting my data `(e.g. b'\xce;\xcb\xa9\xf5\xfe-\xc30\xd6\xee@\xf9Z\x14C\x00\x00\x00\x00')`, and when using `len(data)` I get that the data is length 20, and using `len(data_segments)` the length of 'data_segments' is 4.

```
 def handleNotification(self, cHandle, data):
        data_segments = np.dtype([('timestamp', np.uint32), ('euler_z', np.float32),('euler_y', np.float32),('euler_x', np.float32)])
        human_readable_data = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=data_segments)
        formatted_data = str([x for x in human_readable_data.tolist()[0]])[1:-1]
        formatted_data = self.bluetooth_device_address + ", " + formatted_data
        print(formatted_data)
```

Whenever I add 1 more parameter to data_segments
`data_segments = np.dtype([('timestamp', np.uint32), ('euler_z', np.float32),('euler_y', np.float32),('euler_x', np.float32), ('tmp', np.float32)])`
it works, but I have an extra '0' in my array which I don't use.
Any fixes for this issue, other than just having the extra 0 and removing it in the data printing?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Try `np.frombuffer(data[:16], dtype=data_segments)`